# Can I use UIWebKit in iOS app ? Is there any chance that it will be rejected by Apple?

Tags: ios

I am developing an iPad app which uses webKit to process video content. Some computing needs to be done in the device before rendering the video. It cannot be done as simple web app with video tags and that is why we decided to go with UIWebKit.

I heard the third party browsers were developed using UIWebKit.

http://www.macworld.com/appguide/article.html?article=138409

But following discussion is the concern for me.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54184-app-rejected-webkit-use.html

Is there any chance that Apple reject the app ?

Comment: There is WebKit which is a framework which mobile safari uses, and there is UIWebView which is a component you may use to display web pages, and that also makes use of WebKit. What are you actually talking about?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use private frameworks in your app.  The frameworks mentioned in your second link are still private as of 5.1.  Apple's new static analyzer will surely catch any use of them.  The apps in your first link **probably** use UIWebView, as opposed to WebKit directly.  Why can't you do the same?

Answer (score 0):

As long as use Webkit via UIWebView, you have nothing worry about. That's what all application use. The delegate methods give you all the control you need. The only drawback is that the bridge from Javascript back to Objective-C is slow.

Now including a custom Webkit built from source in your application is an interesting question. The open source Webkit is not the same as calling the Webkit framework that's built into iOS. Not sure if Apple would object to compiling it yourself.